# What is the generalization of Pascal's formula for multi indices?

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra

I am taking a course in PDE and trying to get use to these notations. If I take
3 vectors with nonnegative integers components (n components) that are denoted by $\alpha$,$\omega$,$\gamma$. Is it correct to say that Pascal's formula can be written in the following form?

\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha-\gamma \\
\omega-\gamma
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha-\gamma \\
\omega
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\alpha \\
\omega
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{l}
\alpha \\
\beta
\end{array}\right)=\frac{\alpha !}{\beta !(\alpha-\beta) !}
\end{equation}

and \begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\alpha} !=\alpha_{1} ! \ldots \alpha_{n} !
\end{equation}

I have tried to prove that but I can't see connection between the numerator and denominator in each term (L.H.S).

Comment: What is your definition of $\binom{v}{w}$ for vectors $v,w\in\mathbb R^n$? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: Note that $x!$ is usually not defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$. The most general definition $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$ does not apply to $x\in\{-1,-2,-3,\dots\}$. So maybe your vectors aren't from $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Can you provide a reference where this type of binomial coefficient appears?

Comment: You're right I'm sorry these are vectors with nonnegative integers.

Comment: Is there some restriction on $\gamma$? I would think you'd want the elements to all be $0$s or $1$s, maybe with only a single $1$?

Comment: Just to elaborate on my comment. Your formula is false in the $n=1$ case if $\gamma_1\ne1$. As an example, let $\alpha_1=5$ and $\omega_1=3$. Then for $\gamma_1=2$ the formula would read $$\binom{5-2}{3-2}+\binom{5-2}{3}=\binom{5}{3},$$ which is false. The formula is true, of course, when $\gamma_1=1$.

Comment: $D^{\alpha}(u v)=\sum_{\beta<\alpha}\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha \\ \beta\end{array}\right) D^{\beta} u D^{\alpha-\beta} v=
\sum_{\omega \leq \alpha}\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha-\gamma \\ \omega-\gamma\end{array}\right) D^{\omega} u D^{\alpha-\omega} v+\sum_{\omega \leq \alpha}\left(\begin{array}{c}\alpha-\gamma \\ \omega\end{array}\right) D^{\omega} u D^{\alpha-\omega} v$
   This was my attempt to prove the Leibnitz formula for multi indices, where $\omega=\sigma+\gamma, \beta-\sigma=\alpha-\omega$

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985662/multivariable-multiindex-leibniz-rule) help you? If your real question is about proving the Leibniz rule, you are likely to get more satisfaction by reorienting your question toward that. As mentioned in previous comments, your generalization of Pascal's recurrence is false unless severe restrictions are placed on $\gamma$. If $\gamma$ is $1$ in the $i^\text{th}$ index and $0$ in all other indices, then your formula follows from the single-index Pascal recurrence combined with the distributive law.